# How to change video mode in Debian Wheezy on VirtualBox 4.1.12?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, debian, grub

I've installed Debian Wheezy on VirtualBox 4.1.12 (running in Ubuntu 12.04) and have troubles setting the video mode. `vga=xxx` isn't possible anymore, instead, the video mode should be set using GRUB. In `/etc/default/grub` I set `GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768` and that works, but when I select to boot Debian, it switches back to text mode 80x25. Setting `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX` to `keep` or `1024x768` didn't help.

Any ideas how I could achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you using bios or efi for your VM? have you allocated enought video memory for the VM?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae: I left the default settings, which are BIOS and 12 MB graphics RAM, which should be enough (I never changed that setting and never experienced any problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work for me, I followed the instructions in: https://askubuntu.com/a/18463

### Steps taken for me

Become root user

```
su
```

Open `/etc/default/grub`.

Find `GRUB_GFXMODE= ...` and change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=800x600x32
```

Edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

Find `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ;` and change it to:

```
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600 ; fi
if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=800x600x32 ; fi
```

Find `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}` and change it to:

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}
```

Run:

```
update-grub2
```

## Context

I got this working today.  I therefore do not know how stable the fix is - in terms of updates being applied to grub or the linux kernel.  I hope someone else can clarify whether these settings files every get overwritten by upgrades.

Comment: Using trial-and-error I found out that `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD` in `/etc/default/grub` is being ignored by `update-grub`. In `/etc/grub.d/00_header` it is enough to add the line starting with `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}"` and also the line `set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}`.